# UWP equivalent for WPF Style.Triggers

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I created a control that works in WPF and now trying to port to UWP.

The control exposes a boolean property and when set to true, I change the background color of a Path (Stroke) via a story board with a RepeatBehavior of "forever".

After reading numerous articles I understand UWP uses VisualStates, Interactivity, etc... but no triggers. I have tried reworking the code but not getting the background to change/animate.

**Part of ControlTemplate in WPF**

```
 <Path Fill="Transparent"
      Stroke="{TemplateBinding Outline}"
      StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding Thickness}"
      StrokeDashCap="Flat"
      x:Name="OuterRing">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure x:Name="OutlineFigurePart">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                <ArcSegment x:Name="OutlineArcPart" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>

    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:MyControl}, Path=IsValueOutOfRange}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation To="Red" 
                                                AutoReverse="True"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.8" 
                                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="OuterRing"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation To="LightGray" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                Duration="0:0:0.8"
                                                FillBehavior="Stop"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="OuterRing"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
```

Control used in the view (XAML)

```
<controls:MyControl Width="48" 
                    Height="48"
                    Header="My Header"
                    IsValueOutOfRange="{x:Bind ValueOutOfRange" />
```

1. When **ValueOutOfRange** is set to 'True' from the ViewModel, the Path.Stroke color should animate on 'OuterRing'
2. When **ValueOutOfRange** is set to 'False' from the ViewModel, the Path.Stroke color should go back to normal.

**Part of ControlTemplate in UWP**

```
<Path Fill="Transparent"
      Stroke="{TemplateBinding Outline}"
      StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding Thickness}"
      StrokeDashCap="Flat"
      x:Name="OuterRing">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure x:Name="OutlineFigurePart">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                <ArcSegment x:Name="OutlineArcPart" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>

    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{TemplateBinding IsValueOutOfRange}" Value="True" ComparisonCondition="Equal">
            <media:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                            To="Red" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterRing" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                            AutoReverse="True" 
                            Duration="0:0:8"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </media:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
            </media:ControlStoryboardAction>
        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Path>
```

Comment: Hello, you should include part of your UWP control so far as well to show what you've tried.

Comment: @CorentinPane thanks. part of the UWP control has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, the more common way is to use `VisualStateManager` to process:

According to your code, it can be rewritten like this:

**code-behind**

```cs
public bool IsValueOutOfRange
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsValueOutOfRangeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsValueOutOfRangeProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsValueOutOfRange.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsValueOutOfRangeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsValueOutOfRange", typeof(bool), typeof(PathCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(false,new PropertyChangedCallback(IsValueOutofRange_Changed)));

private static void IsValueOutofRange_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NewValue is bool isOut)
    {
        var instance = d as PathCustomControl;
        if (isOut)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(instance, "Invalid", false);
        else
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(instance, "Normal", false);
    }
}
```

**Template**

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:PathCustomControl">
    <Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Common">
                <VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="Red" 
                                AutoReverse="True"
                                Duration="0:0:0.8" 
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="OuterRing"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="LightGray" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                Duration="0:0:0.8"
                                FillBehavior="Stop"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="OuterRing"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Path Fill="Transparent"
              StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding Thickness}"
              Stroke="{TemplateBinding Outline}"
              StrokeDashCap="Flat"
              x:Name="OuterRing">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure x:Name="OutlineFigurePart">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <ArcSegment x:Name="OutlineArcPart" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When `IsValueOutOfRange` changes, it will switch the control to a different state, thus running different animations.

This is just an example, I use a button on the device to switch the state of the control, it works. But if you want to adapt your project, you need to meet the following two conditions:

1. Provide an initial `Stroke` value
2. The default `IsValueOutOfRange` is `False` when the control is first loaded, so the default color of your `Path` should be the same as the `Normal` state.

Comment: The answer provided by @Richard Zhang worked like a charm. After hours of trying to understand the **VisualStateManager**, it turned out the missing piece was the **IsValueOutofRange_Changed** method.

Thanks Richard!

Comment: it is worth mentioning this is a custom control that derives from **Control** and the UI is defined in a resource dictionary. In my ControlTemplate, I was wrapping certain elements inside a ViewBox and for some reason the VisualStateManager was not firing. I had a couple of controls where one did work and the other one was not working.

After a few hours pulling my hair, I moved the VisuaStateManager outside the ViewBox and everything started working as expected.